# Вывод ошибок

Tags: php, html

Как сделать, чтобы ошибки незаполненных  полей в форме выводились рядом с этим полем, а не на странице обработчика?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если на php, то можно сделать так, что когда обработчик находит ошибку незаполненного поля, но переадресует обратно на страницу с формой, но с каким-нибудь get ?error=1, например. А страница с формой готова принимать такие get и выводить на экран соответствующее сообщение, в зависимости от того, чему равна error. Если вариантов ошибок много, на странице с формой лучше воспользоваться конструкцией switch-case.

Answer (score 1):

проверять введённые данные на соответcтвие какому-либо шаблону до выполнения POST запроса. Например, используя jQuery, получить значения  нужного input, проверить это значение через preg_match и только в случае истины выполнить скрипт.